# Trying to center a view within its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am creating a category on `UIView` to make programmatically positioning and sizing my views easier. I want to create a method that will center a given view horizontally or vertically in its `superview`. So I can do something like the following:

**Category**

```
- (void)centerHorizontally {
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.window.superview.center.x, self.center.y);
}

- (void)centerVertically {
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.window.superview.center.y);
}
```

**Use**

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[v centerHorizontally];
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. What is incorrect about my solution?

Comment: @SathiReddy - please stop needlessly editing questions simply by adding one needless tag. Edit should be useful and complete. Don't just add a tag. Fix everything that might be wrong with a question. Or in this case, don't do anything. Most of your tag edit suggestions are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the view to a parent view before you can center it.

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[someOtherView addSubview:v];
[v centerHorizontally];
```

And your category is incorrect. Don't get the window involved. You need to base it on the superview's size:

```
- (void)centerHorizontally {
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.center.y);
    // or
    self.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.superview.bounds), self.center.y);
}

- (void)centerVertically {
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.superview.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
    // or
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x, CGRectGetMidY(self.superview.bounds));
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `bounds.size.width` and `bounds.size.height` but thank you!

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks.